# istio view configured gateways and virtualservices

Tags: istio

I'm trying to wrap my head around istio gateways and virtual services.  I want to see the configured gateways and virtual services in the system.  How do I view this, is there a kubectl command to view this?

I tried

```
kubectl describe pod istio-ingressgateway-id -n istio-system
```

But this does not give the details or I don't know how to interpret them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Gateway` and `VirtualService` CRDs

Those are Kubernetes CRDs, and you can query them with

`kubectl get Gateway`

And

`kubectl get VirtualService`

For more information, use `kubectl describe`